# Give it a read, read it once, go through it once

Tags: word-usage

If a child doesn't understand a certain topic a teacher sometimes says:

> Just **give it a read** and come to me tomorrow if you don't get it.

Is "give it a read" natural in this context? Does it sound too slangy for a teacher or is a teacher likely to use it?

What about:

> **Just read it once.**
>
> **Just go through it once.**

Does "read it once" sound better than "give it a read"?

Answer (score 2):

"Just go through it once" sounds fine.

"Just read it once" does not sound natural.  It might be said, but there are other, likelier options.

"Just give it a read" is definitely casual, but not necessarily too casual for a teacher to use with a student (that's really a question about teaching styles, more than language styles, but in short most American teachers do not speak particularly formally).

A more likely phrase would be, "give it a try," as long as it's clear from context that "trying" means "reading."

Comment: So is "give it a read" natural? Is it likely to be used?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish, "give it a read" is somewhat natural, but not as likely as "give it a try", "give it a shot" or "give it a go."

Comment: Somewhat natural? So isn't it likely to be used?

Comment: Give it a read, give it a look, give it a look-see, give it a once-over. All of these are acceptable idioms with varying degrees of applicability.

Comment: Hi I had another question: > **We were quite a ways back stuck in traffic yesterday.** 
 _____________________________________________ Actually it is about a few people who take the same bus each day and the bus travels the same route each day. Yesterday they got to their stop late because they were held up by traffic and today they got to their stop on time and thus said this, as at this time yesterday they were stuck in traffic. **Does this sentence sound natural to you? Most of the people don't find it natural.…**

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish, I mostly agree with the answer and commentary given when you posted a similar question a couple weeks ago. This version would make sense if you included "at this time": "We were quite a ways back, stuck in traffic, at this time yesterday."